# How to remove padding / margin in DevExpress Grid Column header

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a DevExpress Grid Control, however, the space in the header is limited so all my text doesn't fit in. There is a rather large padding (or margin maybe) in the header though which if I could reduce would solve my problem. But I can't figure out where the padding is.

The column is defined as...

```
        <dxg:GridColumn
            CellStyle="{StaticResource DefaultCellStyle}"
            CellTemplate="{StaticResource TestCellValueTemplate}"
            FieldName="Test2.DisplayValue"
            Header="{Binding Columns.Test2Column}"
            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource TestColumnHeaderTemplate}"
            HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center"
            Visible="{Binding Columns.Test2Column.IsVisible}"
            VisibleIndex="2" />
```

And `HeaderTemplate`is

```
    <DataTemplate 
        x:Key="TestColumnHeaderTemplate" 
        DataType="vsvm:FvcSessionGridTestColumn">
        <StackPanel
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Text="{Binding Header}" />
            <TextBlock
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                FontSize="11"
                Text="{Binding Time, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=HH:mm:ss}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

No mention of margin or padding anywhere. But while I can control the width of the `StackPanel`, if I make it bigger than the available space, it disappears behind the padding of the cell.

I've tried adding

```
ColumnHeaderContentStyle="{StaticResource DefaultHeaderStyle}"
```

(and also)

```
    <Style x:Key="DefaultHeaderStyle"
           TargetType="{x:Type dxg:HeaderContentControl}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 0, 0, 0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0, 0, 0, 0" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
```

To the `GridColumn` element but it seems to be completely ignored.

[image]

It might be worth noting that I've used "Snoop" to try and find the source of the margin, and it revealed the `ContentMargin` of `13, 12, 13, 12`. If I change this, it seems to work within Snoop. But I don't know where in the code this applies to or where to override it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer eventually here...

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T241104

The solution in my case was to override the `ContentMargin` in ColumnHeaderDockPanel.

Within `<UserControl.Resources>`

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{dxgt:GridColumnHeaderThemeKey ResourceKey=ControlTemplate, IsThemeIndependent=True}" TargetType="{x:Type dxg:GridColumnHeaderBase}">
        <dxg:ColumnHeaderDockPanel x:Name="PART_LayoutPanel" TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource {dxgt:GridColumnHeaderThemeKey ResourceKey=HeaderCaptionForeground}}" ContentMargin="2, 12, 2, 12" />
    </ControlTemplate>
```